# How can a single knife attack deal 61 damage?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In a match between *Natus Vincere* and *Heroic* in ESL Pro League Season 16, at the start of round 10 of the 3rd map Overpass, *sjuush* stabbed his teammate *stavn* with a knife, bringing the latter from 100 HP to 39.

However, according to [CS:GO Wiki](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/Knife), there's no way a single knife slash or stab deals exactly 61 damage. How is this possible?

Here's the [YouTube clip for this event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTXs_c7lBlg&t=2h16m50s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because most instances of friendly fire have damage reduction!

It seemed that *sjuush* performed a secondary attack to *stavn*'s back with his knife. A secondary attack to a player's back deals **153 damage** on an armored target according to the [wiki article you linked](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/Knife).

As this is friendly fire, the damage is reduced. The exact value by which damage is reduced depends on the damage source type, and the reduction value is detailed in the "gamemode_competitive.cfg" file in your CSGO folder. I don't have the game installed anymore, so I snooped around until I found a Reddit user named KiloSwiss who [dumped that info in a comment here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/9y9vmo/comment/e9ztsmd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). The exact values by which friendly fire damage is reduced are:

> ```
> ff_damage_reduction_bullets                       0.33
> ff_damage_reduction_grenade                       0.85
> ff_damage_reduction_grenade_self                  1
> ff_damage_reduction_other                         0.4
> ```

A knife is classified as an "other" type of damage. Assuming *stavn* was armored, if we multiply our original **153 damage** by the `ff_damage_reduction_other` value of **0.4**, it yields **61.2**, which explains why *stavn* only took 61 damage.

Comment: Totally correct! I wasn't aware of FF damage reduction and scratched my head against those numbers for a while. Also FYI: *stavn* was indeed armored (and helmeted) as can be seen in the video.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for that but the competitive spectator UI has changed a lot since I've last watched, so I didn't recognize all the icons. Neat!

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the game's spectator UI. These kinds of events all bring their own UI for broadcasting.